# Display DateTime with additional zoneOffset value if Zone is present

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, time-format, datetimeformatter

While displaying the datetime in specific format is it possible to add the offset value to the hour and date

Example:
Let Say Date Time is `5/12/2023 23:18 PM` is stored without any timezone in DB.
Is it possible to display in particular format (consider PST) as `5/12/2023 10:18 AM`

*tried below methods*

```
DateTimeFormatter COMMENT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER_ZONE = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y hh:mm a zzz");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(date, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
String zonfs = zdt.format(Constants.COMMENT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER_ZONE); //5/12/2023 06:50 PM PDT

DateTimeFormatter COMMENT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y hh:mm a"); //5/12/2023 06:50 PM


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y hh:mm a");
String sdfd =sdf.format(GregorianCalendar.from(zdt).getTime()); //5/13/2023 07:20 AM  here its increasing the day by 1
```

Comment: There’s no reason for you to involve the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class, and you will want not to, java.time and its `DateTimeFormatter` give you all the functionality you need, also for formatting and parsing. Also avoid `GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: You first need to know which time zone your database is using. You can’t convert from an unknown time zone. And by PST did you mean Philippines Standard Time? Pitcairn Standard Time? Those three letter abbreviations are modt often ambiguous. Since your code mentins America/Los_Angeles, it may be what you meant, but please be explicit and clear.

Comment: Perhaps it goes without saying, but if your date and time represents a specific point on the timeline, you should be storing those values a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. What you are doing in storing a date-time without a zone or offset is like storing a price as a number but forgetting the currency — leaving you to assume/guess the meaning of retrieved values.

Comment: `5/12/2023 23:18 PM` Odd...Why the `PM`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, try this way:

```java
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 5, 12, 23, 18);

Instant instant = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZoneId pstZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime pstDateTime = instant.atZone(pstZone);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y hh:mm a");
String formattedDateTime = pstDateTime.format(formatter);
```

Comment: Assuming that the database uses UTC — which is generally recommended — this is correct.